# Edit image preview is not displayed

Tags: images, wp-admin, uploads, media-library

When I click on "Edit" for an image I see the editor and I see the thumbnails on the right, WordPress just won't show me the actual image in the main area.

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=imgedit-preview&_ajax_nonce=de68a01318&postid=29499&rand=385 (couldn't not find image)
```

Here is what I have done to try to fix it:

- Turned off all plugins.
- Remove my own theme and changed to default theme.
- Removed all blank lines and whitespaces in `/wp-content/themes/name/functions.php` + the including files.
- Checked that `php5-gd` is installed.
- Permissions changed to `777` for testing `/wp-content/upload/` + sub folders
- Removed closing `?>` tags in `/wp-content/themes/name/functions.php` + the including files.

Still no preview displayed. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

By default, `wp-config.php` might not have a closing tag `?>` and this is acceptable and by design. The issue may arise from whitespace in some other `.php` file. In my case, I had whitespace after the closing tag of my `functions.php` file for my child theme. Once I removed that whitespace, the images are showing up again and I can crop.

Comment: Brilliant...fixed it for me.

Comment: Just an added note. I had a similar issue but actually had a single space BEFORE my opening `<?php` tag in one of my included files. Fixed the issue, but I never would have found it without this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The preview is now displayed again after I removed empty lines and whitespaces after `?>` in my `wp-config.php` file. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this via a CustomPostType issue.
If the CPT you make doesn't have Revisions turned on, then preview can't show the ACF changes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me I found here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/could-not-edit-image-unable-to-edit-this-image-localhost/

"Just go to php.ini where xampp is installed, assuming it’s C:\xampp\php by default. Open the file, find the line ;extension=gd and remove that semicolon. Restart xampp server and it should work."

Regards
Klaus